# SVN check in and ignoring carriage return

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, checkin

I know that there is a way in SVN settings that can be set to ignore White Space during the DIFF process. But, how do I tell the tool to also ignore white spaces when I am checking in files.

In other words, I want SVN to ignore a white-space change in a file as a new change, and don't let the SVN tool to recognize this change as a valid change ?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in svn.
Whitespaces are important, unlike EOLs you can't just ignore them.